# How to scroll down on applescript?

Tags: google-chrome, applescript

Im trying to make a follow/unfollow bot for Depop. Here is what i got so far.

```
tell application "Safari"
    activate
end tell

set Username to display dialog "What is your Depop username?" default 
answer ""
set Username to text returned of the result

tell application "Safari"
    activate
    open location "https://www.depop.com/" & Username
    delay 5
end tell
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "Safari"
        click at {350, 305} -- {from left, from top}
        click at {350, 305} -- {from left, from top}
        click at {1038, 407} -- {from left, from top}
        click at {1038, 482} -- {from left, from top}
        delay 1
    end tell

end tell
```

I'm trying to make it so it clicks follow and then in a different script it presses unfollow. I'm struggling with how to make it scroll down to click follow/unfollow. Also, if anyone has any ideas on how to make it more efficient then please let me know.

Comment: The problem with this method is that `click at {x, y}`, I believe, interprets the coordinates given as absolute, i.e. relative to the top-left _of the screen_, and not the top-left of the _Safari_ window.  Therefore, if you move your _Safari_ window, your script won't work, because the button won't be at `{350, 305}` anymore.  It will also fail if the font size is changed, or the page's zoom level is changed.

Comment: yeah i know. Is there any way i could fix that?

Comment: Hi, I wonder why you tagged your question as "google-chrome" but your code is for Safari – and does not work with mine at all. . . . Apart from that, if you need to know "absolute" coordinates (with regard to Safari & Screen) this is how to get "screen coordinates" of a window's top-left corner: . . . set xLeft to item 1 of (value of attribute "AXFrame" of window 1 as list) ¬ set yLeft to item 2 of […]. . . . Add xLeft and yLeft to your click-values. . . . But actually it would be much simpler to access your buttons by direct UI scripting. I will describe the fastest way in the next comment >>

Comment: >> To get a (nearly) fool-proof "chain of AS identifiers" do THIS: . . . Open Automator, "New" Programm (Application?), Red button "Record", [Do your clicking], Stop your recording, Copy your "click action" (only), Return to ScriptEditor, Paste from clipboard. . . . This will get you a lot of stuff but also a line:  "set uiScript to "click …" Keep only contents of uiScript and use in your own script. . . . To work flawlessly change all [ \" ] to [ " ], delete double descriptions (e.g. … process "Safari") used already previously. This should save you a lot of scrolling-&-clicking.

Answer (score 0):

You have this page currently open in Safari. So **scroll it along with me**:

```
--- script: scroll Safari current webpage 
-- written: by KniazidisR, today

tell application "Safari" to activate

tell application "System Events"
    key down 63 -- holding Fn key
    -- move carette 40 times down (scroll down)
    repeat 40 times
        key code 125
        delay 0.2
    end repeat
    key up 63 -- release Fn key
end tell

-- NOTE:
-- to scroll up, use 126
```