# How can I use Terminal to tell safari to scroll down by x pixels?

Tags: linux, bash, macos, terminal, automation

I am writing a script to take screenshots of a flash ebook, I have the screen capture part down but I need a way to automate the step to scroll down by say 1000 pixels to get to the next page. How can I do that? Is there a way to send raw trackpad data to Safari?

Comment: You've tagged [linux], but Safari is mac-mostly, and Terminal with a capital T is pretty much a mac
 thing, too.  Does this really have anything to do with Linux?  Hypothetically, would it satisfy you to receive an answer that worked for Linux but not macOS?  Or if you got an answer that works for macOS but not Linux then would that bother you?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51688867/how-to-scroll-down-on-applescript